# putting drop down on page in proper place

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i am designing Daily Attendance System. I have designed a page where Employer can put date range FROM--TO to find attendance of some worker for particular date range now i have been told to put NAME field too like an employer can search by date range but even for particular worker in particular date range. Now i am confused about design that where ti is best to put Name Drop DOwn List, which position on page sounds great for it which will make it better looking.

Interface:

[image]

Comment: You can put it just above the submit button.

Comment: I DID but looked weird sir, any other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                Search By
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Student Name :
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStudentName" Width="320px" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    From Date :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" onkeypress="return false;"
                        Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 70px;">
                    To Date :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" onkeypress="return false;"
                        Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 70px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stack vertically with a two column three row layout. Labels on the left, right justified.